# Apache mod_jk SSL & appBase

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm setting up mod_jk for Apache to use with Tomcat and there are two issues I've ran into.

**SSL**

I have SSL enabled on Apache and all traffic is going through HTTPS, including the requests forwarded to Tomcat. Does Tomcat also need to be configured for SSL in any way or does Apache handle it completely? Everything I have found doesn't say Tomcat needs any configuration but I'm getting the following error in Tomcat which could be related.

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

**appBase/mounting**

My appBase in Tomcat is the typical "path/to/webapps" and when Apache forwards a request it naturally gives it the full path. However, since I only want to forward certain URLs to Tomcat, my JkMount looks something like "JkMount /apps/* worker1". The problem is that Tomcat will be looking for the applications in "path/to/webapps/apps/" which is not the directory the applications get deployed in. Using RewriteRule to remove the "apps" from the path I assume would cause it to not be forwarded to Tomcat. I'm not sure if there are any better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *all traffic is going through HTTPS, including the requests forwarded to Tomcat*

That's not entirely true. If you are using **mod_jk** the requests from Apache to Tomcat use **AJP**, a non encrypted binary protocol. The error you find in the logs means that something is connecting to the **HTTP** connector of Tomcat using a binary protocol. Make sure that you have an AJP connector in your Tomcat configuration:

```xml
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

and you use the same port (e.g. `8009`) instead of the HTTP port in mod_jk's `worker.properties`.

Regarding the **JkMount** directive, it is not possible to rewrite the URI Path using **mod_jk**: if Apache gets a request form `https://example.com/apps/foo/bar` it will ask Tomcat for `/apps/foo/bar`.

If you want Apache to retrieve `/foo/bar` instead you can use [**mod_proxy_ajp**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) instead of mod_jk:

```
ProxyPass "/apps" "ajp://backend.example.com:8009"
```

However I would advise against rewriting the URI Path of the request. If you do it you'll have problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66293644/11748454).

Comment: I've solved the mounting part, however can't find what's causing that error. Apache is properly using the AJP protocol and using the correct ports.

Comment: Usually the error message contains the first bytes of the request, so you can find out what happened. A TLS handshake, e.g. starts with the bytes `\x16\x03`.

Comment: Nevermind, mistake on my part. I was focusing on the server and didn't see I was connecting from port 8080 from the client. Also to anyone else that may have a similar problem with the mounting, The best solution, which I was trying to avoid, is to use JkMount for each individual application.